# Why isn't ng-table populating data from array into table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angular and bootstrap, but I had the normal table working earlier.

I decided to use ng-table because it has a lot of features I wanted, and I'm a bit stuck.

**myApp.html**

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'First Name'">
            {{user.firstName}}
        </td>
        <td title="'Last Name'">
            {{user.lastName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**myAppController.js**

```
app.controller("myAppController", function($scope, NgTableParams){

$scope.names = [{"firstName":"thomas", "lastName":"thomason"},
               {"firstName":"rob", "lastName":"robertson"},
               {"firstName":"john", "lastName":"johnson"}];

$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { data: $scope.names });
```

If I change this to a normal table it works.  I've reviewed all of the examples [here](http://ng-table.com/#/), but there's no real documentation other than examples, and the examples are based off of an older version.

I have the include for ng-tables in another file, and that's working b/c I am able to see the ng-table, but no data is populated.  I'm not getting any errors in the browser, or IDE.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks, and let me know if I need more info.

Comment: I just tossed your code in a JSFiddle and it worked fine. Are you certain there are no errors in the console?

Comment: There are definitely no errors in the console.  It's doing everything correctly, but the array isn't pulling in.  Would you mind linking to a jsfiddle where this works?

Comment: [Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/u0tk16so/). I just realized that the CDN I referenced is version 0.8.3 (not sure if a 1.0 release ever hit). For some reason the styling is messed up, but the table itself displays data.

Comment: Yeah...so if you update the CDN to use the latest 1.0 beta then you have to make the change that Richard noted: use `dataset` instead of `data`.

Comment: 0.8.3 is correct, that's the version I'm using at least.  That jsfiddle is really odd.  I'm going to look into that for a bit.  I'll get back with you

Comment: @Lex I'm using 0.8.3, and I need to stick with that.  I'm pretty certain you have to stay with just data and not dataset in that version.

Comment: Your fiddle is making me think the problem isn't with this code directly though.

Comment: I accepted the answer below since my problem ended up being specific to my situation.  I think the answer below will help others.  Just an FYI the fiddle you posted takes on all of the correct formatting if you add [this](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css) external resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { data: $scope.names });
```

try setting the above line to this

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: $scope.names });
```

It seems as though the variable that is used by NgTable is parsed into $data from dataset. I noticed that was the only thing noticeably different in the example.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the question, but I'm using version 0.8.3, and need to stay with that.  In version 1.0beta I think you're correct, but in 0.8.3 which I'm using, it is still data.  Sorry about that.  Upvoting the answer since I'm sure this will help someone else eventually.